# Find Maclaurin series and radius of convergence. Compare with geometric series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the MacLaurin series and radius of convergence of: $$\frac{1}{(2+z^4)}$$

What can I compare this to? Can I compare it to a geometric series? What is the radius of convergence?

Since $$\frac{1}{1-z} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^n = 1 + z  + z^2 + ...$$

Does this help here? Can I transform the original function to:

$$\frac{1}{1+\frac{z^4}{4}} =\frac{1}{1-\frac{-z^4}{4}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{-z^4}{4})^n = 1 - \frac{z^4}{4}  + \frac{z^8}{4} + ... $$

Is this valid? What's the radius of convergence of a geometric series? It's when |z| < 1 right? Does that apply here too?

Comment: I think my signs are incorrect and that the radius for some reason in my book is is $\sqrt[4]{2}$

Comment: The series an alternating series: the terms are alternately positive and negative. The series converges if $|\frac {-z^{4}} 4| <1$ and diverges if $|\frac {-z^{4}} 4| >1$ so the radius of convergence is $\sqrt 2$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be the 4th root?

Comment: $|z^{4}| <4$ if $|z^{2}| <2$ or $|z| <\sqrt 2$.

Comment: Wanna give a full answer and I'll give you credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done is correct except for the last equality. The terms of the series are alternately positive and negative,.

The series converges if $|\frac {-z^{4}} 4| <1$ or $|z|^{2} <2$ of $|z| <\sqrt2 $ and diverges if $|z| >\sqrt 2$ so the radius of convergence is $\sqrt 2$.

Comment: Did I transform my equation correct?

Comment: I think I didn't transform my equation correctly which is probably why my radius of convergence is wrong. Generally speaking, when you transform an equation like this to resemble the geometric series, how do we find the radius of convergence?

Comment: @Jwan622 The radius of converegence is given by $\frac 1 R=\lim \sum |a_n|^{1/n}$.